# ASP.NET MVC 4 with EF code tuning issue

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

The following code snippet is from our ASP.NET MVC 4 application that builds a menu based on the user. We're also using EF 6

MenuBarController

```
public ActionResult GetMenuList()
{
    using (spc_aspEntities db = new spc_aspEntities())
    {
        ProgramMenuDAL programMenuDAL = new ProgramMenuDAL(db);
        List<ProgramMenuDTO> programMenuList = programMenuDAL.GetMenuListForUser("1");
        return View(programMenuList);
    }
}
```

ProgramMenuDAL

```
public class ProgramMenuDAL : BaseDAL
{
    private const string TOP_MENU_TYPE = "Menu";
    private const string SUB_MENU_TYPE = "Submenu";

    public ProgramMenuDAL(spc_aspEntities dbContext)
        : base(dbContext)
    {
    }

    public List<ProgramMenuDTO> GetMenuListForUser(string userLoginId)
    {
        //Get user info first
        var userInfo = _dbContext.USER_TB.First(x => x.USER_SABUN == userLoginId);
        string userGroupId = userInfo.USER_LEVEL;

        //Retrieve all top menu first 
        var topMenuList =
            from program_tb in _dbContext.PROGRAM_TB
            where program_tb.PROGRAM_GB == TOP_MENU_TYPE
            orderby program_tb.PROGRAM_ORDER
            select new { program_tb.PROGRAM_ID, program_tb.PROGRAM_NAME };

        Debug.Assert(topMenuList.Any(), "Top Menu is Empty");

        List<ProgramMenuDTO> programMenuList = new List<ProgramMenuDTO>();

        //Retrieve all sub menus
        foreach (var topMenu in topMenuList)
        {
            var subMenuList =
                from program_tb in _dbContext.PROGRAM_TB
                from group_auth_tb in _dbContext.GROUP_AUTH_TB
                where program_tb.PROGRAM_ID == group_auth_tb.PROGRAM_ID
                && program_tb.PROGRAM_SYSTEM == topMenu.PROGRAM_NAME
                && program_tb.PROGRAM_GB == SUB_MENU_TYPE
                && group_auth_tb.GROUP_ID == userGroupId
                && group_auth_tb.OPEN_YN == "True"
                orderby program_tb.PROGRAM_ORDER
                select new { program_tb.PROGRAM_ID, program_tb.PROGRAM_NAME };

            if (!subMenuList.Any())
                continue;

            List<ProgramSubMenuDTO> programSubMenuList = new List<ProgramSubMenuDTO>();
            subMenuList.ToList().ForEach(x=>programSubMenuList.Add(new ProgramSubMenuDTO(x.PROGRAM_ID, x.PROGRAM_NAME)));

            programMenuList.Add(new ProgramMenuDTO(topMenu.PROGRAM_ID,topMenu.PROGRAM_NAME,programSubMenuList));
        }

        return programMenuList;
    }
}
```

BaseDAL

```
public abstract class BaseDAL
{
    protected readonly spc_aspEntities _dbContext;

    protected BaseDAL(spc_aspEntities dbContext)
    {
        if (dbContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Database Context cannot be null");
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
}
```

The view corresponding to the controller is then loaded onto our shared layout using RenderAction.

```
 @{Html.RenderAction("GetMenuList", "Menubar");}
```

Here are my question:

1. Does the code look sound architecturally? I've tried to separate business logic and data access layer (We've decided on not using the repository pattern). You can see that the query looks quite awkward, but given our initial database design, it seems like there's really no way around it.
2. This code is slowing down our website quite a bit. Before, each request to the main index would take about 50ms. Now it takes 500ms in debug mode, 200ms in release mode. What are some strategies I can use to tune the code?

--Edit--

One more question

1. We're wrapping all dbcontexts in using statement, requiring us to write the same code in every action. Would it be fine to just declare a private variable for the database and use it in the same class? What are some strategies around this?

Comment: This is terrible EF code. Do a quick search on `Select n + 1` and `Eager Loading`. Try to reduce the number of queries down to 1 if possible. PS please post in CodeReview next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cringe when I see DAL and DTO combined with Entity Framework. EF is your DAL and provides DTO classes you can extend. You generally project the EF classes into Models in MVC.

Personally I would extend your DbContext with extra methods for specific tasks, and also avoid doing a query inside a for-each loop.

```
public partial class spc_aspEntities
{
    public List<Models.ProgramMenu> GetMenuForUser(string userLoginId)
    {
        // existing code to get USER_LEVEL..

        // create a single query to get your full menu structure
        // your EF model should already include the relationship 
        // between PROGRAM_TB and GROUP_AUTH_TB
        var query = this.PROGRAM_TB
            .Where(p => p.PROGRAM_GB == TOP_MENU_TYPE)
            .OrderBy(p => p.PROGRAM_ORDER)
            .Select(p => new {
                p.PROGRAM_ID, 
                p.PROGRAM_NAME,
                // assuming there's also a relationship defined
                // between PROGRAM_TB and itself on 
                // PROGRAM_SYSTEM == (parent).PROGRAM_NAME
                SubMenus = p.ChildPrograms
                    .Where(cp => cp.PROGRAM_GB == SUB_MENU_TYPE)
                    .Where(cp => cp.GroupAuths
                        .Any(g => g.GROUP_ID == userGroupId 
                            && g.OPEN_YN == "True"
                        )
                    )
                    .Select(cp => new { cp.PROGRAM_ID, cp.PROGRAM_NAME })
            });

            // now project this into your model, ToList() forces the query to run so
            // we can then perform non-sql manipulation (like newing up objects etc)
            var programMenuList = query.ToList()
                .Select(anon => new Models.ProgramMenu(
                    anon.PROGRAM_ID, 
                    anon.PROGRAM_NAME, 
                    anon.SubMenus.Select(sub => new Models.ProgramSubMenu(
                        sub.PROGRAM_ID, 
                        sub.PROGRAM_NAME
                    ).ToList()
                )).ToList();

            return programMenuList;
    }
}
```

All this is created without any testing or deeper knowledge of your system. I see many issues with names and structure here, I've left most as-is but I would seriously consider code-readability as an important feature.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. There seems to be one issue though. We're using database first design as we're forced to use a really-old (and frankly badly designed as you pointed out) database that's been in use by another application. We can't make any modifications to db. Your example seems to be relying on the fact that I have full control over the EF classes generated (I.E: ChildPrograms), but since the EF designer generated classes for me to use, I'm inclined to think I don't have anyway to make such modification. What should I do in this case? Sorry about not pointing this out earlier.

Comment: @l46kok a big project I am working on is also based on an existing database with many issues, one being no foreign keys in the DB. I still updated the EF designer to have all the relationships I needed, and in some cases renamed the properties to make the code more readable. The biggest issue with this is if the table changes you will probably have to manually re-apply those changes if you regenerate the class. Try changing things in the EF Designer yourself and see, it works well even for database-first.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should add cache, because I am sure that menu doesn't change for user.

The second problem is that you don't get whole menu in one query instead you run query for each submenu.